# Convert HTML to react material ui

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, formatting

I am porting an app from html to React.
I have about 400 lines of html in one or two files that I dont want to have to manually convert into Grid and other components of reacts material-ui.

For example I have quite a lot of:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
   // ...
           <div class="griditem">
                <input type="text" class="input" />
              </div>
              <div class="griditem red">
                <input type="text" class="input" />
              </div>
```

I would like to convert this into Grid input text keeping the styles from style1.css.  Is there a website or a plugin to do this?  So effectively I'd like to change the above into:

```
import "./style1.css";
       <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            autoComplete="fname"
            name="firstName"
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="firstName"
            label="First Name"
            value={fname}
            onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)}
            autoFocus
          />
        </Grid>
```

Theres quite a bit of these to do so it would be much more efficient if there was a plugin or library to do this.